# SlectedItem dropdown not showing values

Tags: java, smartgwt

I am working on smartGwt project i have developed simple slectedItem dropdown. This dropdown does not showing any vaules for slection this is multiple selction dropdown. below is my code

```
final Window winModal = new Window();
        winModal.setWidth(700);
        winModal.setHeight(400);
        winModal.setAutoSize(true);
        winModal.setTitle("Schedule");
        winModal.setShowMinimizeButton(false);
        winModal.setIsModal(true);
        winModal.setShowModalMask(true);
        winModal.centerInPage();


        DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
        form.setHeight100();
        form.setWidth100();
        form.setPadding(5);
        form.setLayoutAlign(VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);

        SelectItem selectItemMultiplePickList = new SelectItem();  
        selectItemMultiplePickList.setTitle("Select Multiple");  
        selectItemMultiplePickList.setMultiple(true);  
        selectItemMultiplePickList.setMultipleAppearance(MultipleAppearance.PICKLIST);  
        selectItemMultiplePickList.setValueMap("Cat", "Dog", "Giraffe", "Goat", "Marmoset", "Mouse");  

        form.setFields(selectItemMultiplePickList);

        winModal.addItem(form);
        winModal.show();
```

my dropdown widget is showing but not showing any values inside dropdown

anyhelp

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try with `winModal.addMember(form);` instead of `winModal.addItem(form);`?

Comment: I just tried your code exactly as posted and it works on `GWT`: `2.7.0` and `SmartGWT` : `6.0`. SelectItem expands and all values show up. https://i.imgur.com/1tW71f8.png

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hacky but a quick way to use a select without a datasource is to set the special values:

https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-release/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/SelectItem.html#setSpecialValues-java.util.LinkedHashMap-